# What is the difference between GT and HI instruction in ARM architecture?

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded

"GT" is greater than and "HI" is higher than. I think both have the same meaning.[The instruction Set Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdqHh.png)

Comment: Why did you not read the detailed description? It is very clear about the differences.

Answer (score 7):

HI instruction takes its operands as unsigned so basically it uses C and Z flag for its operation
On the other hand GT or GE takes operands as signed numbers and uses flags N(negative) and V(overflow). Both GE and GT are same but GE accepts a cleared Z flag, too.
So if you are using unsigned numbers then both will produce same output.

Answer (score 5):

Signed vs unsigned comparison

```
GT  Signed greater than
HI  Unsigned higher
```

Answer (score 1):

The ARM documentation clearly states that

> HI Unsigned higher C set and Z clear
>
> GT Signed greater than Z clear, and either N set and V set, or N clear and V clear (Z == 0,N == V)

They are different conditions.